# Can't load docker from saved tar image

Tags: docker

I committed my container as an image, then used "docker save" to save the image as a tar. Now I'm trying to load the tar on a GCC Centos 7 instance. I packaged it locally on my Ubuntu machine.

I've tried: `docker load < image.tar` and `sudo docker load < image.tar`

I also tried `chmod 777 image.tar` to see if the issue was permissions related.

Each time I try to load the image I get a variation of this error (the xxxx bit is a different number every time):

`open /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-import-xxxxxxxxx/repositories: no such file or directory`

I think it might have something to do with permissions, because when I try to cd into /var/lib/docker/ I run into permissions issues.

Are there any other things I can try? Or is it likely to be a corrupted image?

Comment: Are you sure `docker save` executed successfully? What is the size of the generated tar file?

Comment: Also, you said that you've created a tar image from a container using `docker save` but to create images from containers the actual command is `docker commit`, not `save`, which is used to create tar files from images (not containers!) - So am I right to assume that you executed `docker commit` first? Or, instead, that you said 'container' but meant 'image'?

Comment: @PedroA I didn't see anything that made me think docker save didn't work correctly, although the end image was about 3.2GB. and also, yes, I committed the changes and then "saved" the image to a tar - I will change the question to make this clearer

Comment: You should read about how to [build and run custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/): using `docker commit` is almost never considered a best practice.  A more typical workflow is to write a `Dockerfile` that describes how to build an image and check that in to source control, and either `docker build` the same image on the second host or `docker push` the image to a registry.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There was a simple answer to this problem

I ran md5 checksums on the images before and after I moved them across systems and they were different. I re-transferred and all is working now.

Comment: If this solved your problem, mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: sometimes thereis no available disk space when you copy the image. i had the same probleme.

Comment: In my case the tar file was from a container, not an image.  So I have to use `docker import` instead of `docker load`

Comment: this also solved my problem, i found my imagefile is 0bit.i got a similar error message

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and the following command fixed it for me:

cat <file_name>.tar | docker import - <image_name>:<image_version/tag>

Ref: https://webkul.com/blog/error-open-var-lib-docker-tmp-docker-import/

Answer (score 6):

for me the problem was that I added .tgz as an input. Once I extracted the tarball - there were the .tar file. Using that file as input it was successful.

Comment: I'll probably try this next, it's weird I had no problems with the tgz file for over a year now and suddenly this occured.

Comment: Thank you! 2 years later and still an issue - `docker save` saves stuff as .tar - I right-clicked in the file manager to pack is as `.tar.xz` and I assumed it just added .xz so I was extracting only the xz part instead of both - `tar -xvf image.tar.xz` got me my `image.tar` back and it could be loaded. :)

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Ubuntu 22.04) the problem was using the `/tmp/` folder. After having moved the tar file to `~/mytmp/` docker can load the tar file.

Using the `/var/` folder. as in the original post, might have similar effects(?)

Comment: I can confirm this also worked for me on 22.04, but I have no clue why this happens, worked fine for me from /tmp in ubuntu 20

Answer (score 1):

The sequence of the BUILD(!) command is important, try this sequence:

```
### 1/3: Build it:
    # docker build -f MYDOCKERFILE -t MYCNTNR .

### 2/3: Save it:
    # docker save -o ./mycontainer.tar MYCNTNR

### 3/3: Copy it to the target machine:
    # rsync/scp/...  mycontainer.tar    someone@target:.

### 4/4: On the target, load it :
    # docker load -i MYCNTNR.tar
    <snip>
    Loaded image: MYCNTNR
```

Comment: you `save` the image, not the container.