# docker load command failing with " no such file or directory" error

Tags: docker, ubuntu, tar

I am attempting to load a docker image from a tar file (that was previously created using docker save) on Ubuntu V23.10. I am putting the tar (worker.tar) file in a directory called /web/tars.

I cd into /web/tars and do an ls -l to get:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 583469654 May 31  2022 worker.tar
```

I then invoke the command:

```
docker load --input worker.tar
```

and get the following response:

```
open worker.tar: no such file or directory
```

This makes no sense, because when I do a "tar tvf worker.tar", I get a list of all the image layers that were saved to the tar file. Furthermore, if I do a docker load on other operating systems, I have no problem "finding" the tar file.

So why is docker unable to "find" my tar file on Ubuntu?

Comment: did u try with the full (absolute) path of "worker.tar"?

Comment: when u run 'ls -l', did u see only "emailer.tar"? u are trying to load another file "worker.tar"..

Comment: Omer: (1): sorry, the ls -l that I entered was for a tarfile of another container which I accidently copied here. I have corrected my error with the listing for worker.tar.

Comment: As for using the full path: that actually was the second thing I tried before coming to Stack Overflow.. First I tried ./worker.tar, , then I tried/web/tars/worker.tar. docker returned the same "no such file or directory" error.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It worked. One thing I am noticing: docker on Ubuntu apparently does not "see" any files that are in the directories I place them in. I actually tried a docker build on my Ubuntu and got "no such file" error finding the Dockerfile! Something is very wrong with Docker on Ubuntu. I will be finding the proper place to file some bug reports on it.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `<` as alternatively:

```
docker load < worker.tar
```

With `--input`, it reads from `tar archive file`, instead of `STDIN`:

```
docker load --input /web/tars/worker.tar
```

**Ref:**   https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/

You mentioned that `<` works, but `--input` doesn't work. I don't know the exact reason, but it may be related to file permissions, maybe if your docker doesn't access the file to load. You may also check the docker daemon logs to find the error (for ubuntu, journalctl):

```
sudo journalctl -fu docker.service
```

Another way:

```
cat worker.tar | docker import - <image_name>:<image_version/tag>
```

**Ref:** [Can't load docker from saved tar image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499389/cant-load-docker-from-saved-tar-image)